# HTML if image is not found

Tags: html

I have an image in a HTML page:

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="32" height="32" />
```

If the image is not found on the server it shows an ugly blank square.

I want to make it so that if an image is not found it will display nothing or some other default image that I know is definitely on the server.

How can this be done?

Comment: I'm getting favicons, some sites don't have them.

Comment: In that case, maybe do a server-side or client-side request first to see what status code comes back?

Comment: I'm trying to not use js because I don't like slow websites and theres too many favicons to do it server side, it would get the server banned.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Of course you should have functioning links on the site. What if the links aren't on your own site, but someone else's? Or what if they're coming from a remote data store and taking a while to download?

Answer (score -35, accepted):

Solution - I removed the height and width elements of the img and then the alt text worked.

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="32" height="32" />
```

TO

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" />
```

Thank you all.

Comment: So you gave youself the "correct answer" but you answered with an answer unrelated to the question, GG WP.

Comment: oh this guy accepted his own answer out of all this correct answers hahaha, good way to cherish urself.

Comment: It's not the first time :D https://stackoverflow.com/a/12768098/1545917

Comment: This answer did not provide an alternative image.

Comment: @david19801 care to explain?

Answer (score 375):

The best way to solve your problem:

```
<img id="currentPhoto" src="SomeImage.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='Default.jpg'" alt="" width="100" height="120">
```

`onerror` is a good thing for you :)

Just change the image file name and try yourself.

Comment: Combined with a useful alt tag this is a great way to solve the problem!

Comment: If Default.jpg is not available you will end up in an endless loop. You should add a check `if (this.src != 'Default.jpg')`

Comment: To avoid infinite loops and better than the if : `this.onerror=null;` as given below by @Sudarshan.

Comment: anyone working with react, you can refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097560/react-js-replace-img-src-onerror

Comment: Thanks this will working fine, i have one question can i do  something for console error for that.

Comment: icanuse, https://www.caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_img_onerror, lists onerror as "This feature is deprecated/obsolete and should not be used." As well as this is not supported for IE11 (for those who have to give commercial support)

Answer (score 38):

Well you can try this.

```
  <object data="URL_to_preferred_image.png" type="image/png">
   <img src="URL_to_fallback_image.png" />
  </object>
```

this worked for me. let me know about you.

Comment: Seems works in all major browsers. Just swap default and original. So that object renders original image and img default one

Comment: Not supported in IE11 (for those who have to continue LTS commercial support for IE)

Comment: Not working for me. Code check says you can't have an <img /> inside an <object />.

Comment: Think you have sources swapped. It works if `object` attribute `data` is the first choice image and the `img` attribute `src` is the default image path.

Answer (score 20):

For the alternative, if the image doesn't exist - show nothing at all. (what I was looking for)

You can swap the function from Robby Shaw's answer in the "onerror" attribute to "this.remove()".

```html
<img id="currentPhoto" src="SomeImage.jpg" alt='1' width="100" height="120">
<img id="currentPhoto" src="SomeImage.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();" alt="2" width="100" height="120">
```

Answer (score 15):

Ok but I like to use this way, so that whenever original image is not available you can load your default image that may be your favorite smiley or image saying Sorry ! Not Available, But in case if both the images are missing you can use text to display. where you can also you smiley then. have a look almost covers every case.

```
<img src="path_to_original_img/img.png"  alt="Sorry! Image not available at this time" 
       onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='<?=base_url()?>assets1/img/default.jpg';">
```

Comment: Don't use alt for error texts if you want page to be parsed correctly by search engines. Search engines could index your content data incorrectly.

Comment: What does `<?=base_url()?>` do? Why do you surprisingly add some server-side and framework-based code?

Comment: @NicoHaase its url from php framework, well you can always write your own url for image, i have given an example that doesnt mean you should copy and paste it or concentrate on that url, you include your url it means. To explain you have to give example so i did.

Answer (score 3):

You can show an alternative text by adding `alt`:

```
<img src="my_img.png" alt="alternative text" border="0" />
```

Comment: maybe this square comes from the div (or another tag) that contains your img

Comment: alt doesn't seem to work if the img display style is 'block'

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to handle this scenario is by setting the `alt` tag to something meaningful.

If you want a default image instead, then I suggest using a server-side technology to serve up your images, called using a similar format to:

```
<img src="ImageHandler.aspx?Img=Blue.jpg" alt="I am a picture" />
```

In the `ImageHandler.aspx` code, catch any file-not-found errors and serve up your `default.jpg` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I added a parent div around the image and used the following onerror event handler to hide the original image because in IE there was still an ugly image-not-found image shown after using the alt attribute:

```
<div style=" width:300px; height:150px; float:left; margin-left:5px; margin-top:50px;">
        <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Logo-Left.png")' onerror="this.parentElement.innerHTML = '';" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here Check below code snippet which, In this, I miss-spelled the image name. So, just because of that it is showing the alternative image as not found image ( 404.svg ).

```html
<img id="currentPhoto" src="https://www.ccrharrow.org/Images/content/953/741209.pg" onerror="this.src='https://www.unesale.com/ProductImages/Large/notfound.png'" alt="">
```

Comment: icanuse, https://www.caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_img_onerror, lists onerror as "This feature is deprecated/obsolete and should not be used." As well as this is not supported for IE11 (for those who have to give commercial support)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366589/458321 - best practice is to set this up in a script, not as an attribute. The attribute is deprecated, not the event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `border=0` in the `img` tag to make the ugly square go away.

`<img src="someimage.png" border="0" alt="some alternate text" />`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to  hide the space occupied by `<img>` tag so this worked for me

`<img  src = "source.jpg" alt = "" >`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative image instead of a text, you can as well use php:

```
$file="smiley.gif";
$alt_file="alt.gif";
if(file_exist($file)){
     echo "<img src='".$file."' border="0" />";
}else if($alt_file){
     // the alternative file too might not exist not exist
     echo "<img src='".$alt_file."' border="0" />";
}else{
  echo "smily face";
}
```

Comment: You don't know if they're running PHP

Answer (score 0):

simple way to handle this, just add an background image.

Answer (score 0):

I was having EXACTLY the same issue, and my internet seach brought me here. Thanks to
Robert's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7995298/4012770) I obtained what I needed.

Mi issue is that I have a flask template that applies on several different paths, sometimes picture exists, sometimes not. My source, now:

```html
<h1 id="Titulo">Text that will be shown if image fails to load</h1>
<img src="/path_to_picture" onload="document.getElementById('Titulo').style.display = 'none'; return true;" onerror="this.style.display = 'none'; return true;">
```

So I print the text in one object with ID (in my case, title) AND I try to output the picture. If picture loads, I hide the text; if it doesn't load, I hide the picture (so no ugly broken icon is shown).

I know, old post... but it poped up when I searched so maybe this is useful for someone else... sometime.

Answer (score -1):

its works for me that if you dont want to use alt attribute if image break then you can use this piece of code and set accordingly.

```
<h1>
  <a> 
   <object data="~/img/Logo.jpg" type="image/png">
     Your Custom Text Here
   </object>
  </a>
</h1>
```

Answer (score -2):

This one worked for me. using the srcset. I have just learnt about it so i dont know if browsers support it but it has worked for me. Try it and later give me your feed back.

```
 <img src="smiley.gif" srcset="alternatve.gif" width="32" height="32" />
```

Answer (score -2):

try PHP

```
if (file_exists('url/img/' . $Image)) {
    $show_img_URL = "Image.jpg";
} else {
    $show_img_URL = "Image_not_found.jpg";
}
```