# MYSQL count of count?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation

I have a mysql table like:

```
id, visitorid, pageid
```

When a visitor hits the website it stores their visitor id and the page id as a row.

I am trying to extract the number of visitors who hit the website exactly X times. (for a chart). so how many visit just one page, how many visit 2 pages...

so far I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(visid),visid FROM vislog GROUP BY visid ORDER BY COUNT(visid) DESC
```

But I don't know how to do the next part of counting the counts.

Is it possible to do as a MySQL query?

Comment: You mean GROUP BY based on a GROUPY BY result?

Comment: I think I mean count(count(visid)) and count(visid).  so number who visited once was xx and visited twice was yy and...

Comment: You can (and probably should) add your answer as an answer, not just an edit of the question. )

Comment: You actually *should* add your edit as an answer (but it's fair to keep the other answer accepted if it helped you because it's a way to say thank you).

Comment: okay, I have added it now but it says wait 2 days to accept so I chose the other answer for now.

Comment: @hakre: Does the OP's answer add any value? It's basically the same as mine, with a few aliases renamed.

Comment: @ypercube: Yes this seems fishy.

Comment: @hakre, what do you mean fishy?  My answer was correct and worked.  The code was simple and easy for me to understand.  ypercube had complicated code.  For someone searching the answer I think mine is better...I will not revenge downvote his like he has done to mine.  I just want things to be clear to searchers because I use this site too.

Comment: @David19801: In my eyes, you should pay more respect for those that helped, yes. You were able to compile your answer *after* others have shown you the way. It's fishy then to accept your own answer later on, you can leave your answer here and if future users find it useful, they will upvote it. And it is not true that ypercube's code is harder to understand for the general audience. It is for you because it's your code, others need to first read the question, see if it fits their need and then a well documented answer is better because it helps.

Comment: I hope you can understand that. Suggestion: Reconsider where you want to place your acceptance and I'll reconsider my voting, too.

Comment: @David19801: So I do the first step, I removed my downvote.

Comment: For the record, I did not revengefully downvoted. And hakre has not posted answer here, so (if he downvoted), where's the revenge? People downvote for various reasons. Maybe your answer does not have very clear code (or others think so) or it is a copy of mine (or others think so). That's why downvotes are anonymous, so there are no revenges.

Answer (score -11, accepted):

I could solve it this way:

```
SELECT cnt, COUNT(cnt) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(visid) as cnt FROM vislog GROUP BY visid
) x GROUP BY cnt ORDER BY cnt ASC
```

The little `x` is important.

Comment: How is that little `x` called and how does it work? And what do you do with the new table then? Don't you need to remove it from the database after you've executed this query? ;)

Comment: I have no idea.  I just know it works and was giving table error when I did not have it.  Do I need to remove it?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'd say it is generealy useful, after making such a discovery, to actually understand it. One way to see if oneself understands something is explaining it to others, e.g. in the answer. This is how a Q&A site works best.

Comment: You can search the Mysql manual. I think it is with subqueries. Also you don't need to make that bold. Everybody sees that it is by you. I also placed a link in your question, so it is really prominent.

Comment: The `x` is called an alias. Derived tables (as in this case) have to have an alias. You can use either `AS x` or just `x` (the `AS` is optional). It's the same as the `AS grp` in my answer and the `AS a` in another answer.

Comment: I see, so it is not a real table, just a pretend table for mysql so mysql can treat it like a table?

Comment: It's not a **base** table, not even a temporary table, it's a derived table. It's still a table though (with a very small lifetime). The `x` is the name of this derived table (which is probably evaluated for every execution of the query and then removed). You don't have to do anything to remove it. You can't keep it actually, it's all done internally by the sql engine.

Comment: I fail to see how this is different from the answer @ypercube provided.

Answer (score 14):

You can wrap your query inside another one:

```
SELECT
    cnt      AS page_visits
  , COUNT(*) AS number_of_visitors
FROM
    ( SELECT 
          COUNT(*) AS cnt                --- use: COUNT(DISTINCT page_id)
                                         --- for a different count
      FROM vislog 
      GROUP BY visid
   ) AS grp
GROUP BY cnt 
ORDER BY number_of_visitors ;
```

or (I suppose this makes more sense for passing the numbers to a chart), remove the `ORDER BY` which is the same as putting:

```
ORDER BY cnt ;
```

Comment: This is too complex but I used it for my answer.  I added my answer to the question.

Answer (score 11):

One way to do it is to wrap this query into another one:

```
SELECT COUNT(visid) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(visid) AS cvisid, visid 
      FROM vislog 
  GROUP BY visid 
  HAVING cvisid = 2) AS c
```

But I think you need to get the histogram of visits: this can be done with PHP (assuming the query is the same as in the question):

```
$results = array();
// query preparation skipped, as it's obviously done by the OP himself
while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
  $count = $row['cvisid'];
  if (isset($results[$count])) {
    $results[$count]++;
  }
  else {
    $results[$count] = 1;
  }
}
```

Or with MySQL itself:

```
SELECT cvisid, 
       COUNT(cvisid) AS cnt 
  FROM (
    SELECT visid,
           COUNT(visid) AS cvisid 
      FROM vislog 
  GROUP BY visid ) AS c
GROUP BY cvisid
```

Comment: What is HAVING?  I have never seen that before

Comment: @raina77ow: for reporting it's normally better to have a SQL query, not a PHP script. Just saying. Naturally you could calculate everything in PHP, however the database is normally better with that.

Comment: @hakre Well, there's a way to do a histogram in MySQL, but I admit I never done it over 'inner histograms'. ) Will update my answer, though.

Comment: @raina77ow : I doubt this query may result in an error `1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @KhaleelAKarim Thank you, fixed this and another (syntax) typo.

Answer (score 1):

Raina77ow (2nd reply) returned a clean solution in his third block of code

```
    SELECT cvisid, 
           COUNT(cvisid) AS cnt 
      FROM (
        SELECT visid,
               COUNT(visid) AS cvisid 
          FROM vislog 
      GROUP BY visid ) AS c
    GROUP BY cvisid
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using following query

```
SELECT COUNT(a.page_visits) AS no_of_visitors, a.page_visits AS page_count
FROM(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pageid) AS page_visits
FROM vislog
GROUP BY visid) AS a
GROUP BY a.page_visits;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Yes, this but how to do for all numbers so I don't have to run the query for every number menually?  can it all be done with just a query?