# Showing WebP images only if they exist

Tags: html, responsive-design, webp

I'm trying to migrate to using WebP images on our website.

We have quite a few images in our S3 buckets, so it would take a while to convert all of them to webp. Instead, I'd like to show webp *only if* the webp version is available (it'll have a deterministic URL structure); and if not, show the original JPG/PNG.

When I try the following, it doesn't work (don't worry the icons on the top right. also `webpImageUrl` and `originalImageUrl` have the correct values):

```
<picture>
   <source srcSet={`${webpImageUrl}`} type="image/webp" />
   <img src={`${originalImageUrl}`} />
</picture>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which framework are you using? You cannot do this in HTML itself, but if you are using a JS framework anyway, it is possible. (In such case, you would probably also write `<img src={originalImageUrl}/>` instead of string interpolation, which is not needed here.

Comment: I am using React, I believe some trick with `onError` should get me what I need

Comment: (something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097560/react-js-replace-img-src-onerror , but for `picture` tag )

Comment: While the img onerror will functionally solve your issue, keep in mind that you'll be adding an additional round trip before non-webp image is fetched. So, if you have more non-webp images than webp images - I'd recommend not moving to webp until conversion completes.