# Check Image URL before updating State in React / Next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**The logic below is in: React / Nextjs with styled-components.**

Hello, I have a component that "renders" a blog banner (**background-image**), the url comes from a **state** that already has a standard image.

```
const [blogBanner, setBlogBanner] = useState ('/ images / imageBlogDefault.png')
```

But before the component receives this state, the code checks whether that blog already has a user-defined banner. If so, then take the url and update the **state**.

```
if (props.blog.image) {
    setBlogBanner (`$ {hlp.BACKEND_HOST} / images / blogBanners / $ {props.blog.image}`)
}
```

> And in styled-components I use **background-image: url (blogBanner)**.

**The problem** is that the request that takes the blogs returns only the banner url and not the image itself, so if for some reason the image is deleted from the database without removing the url from it on the blog ... when loading this blog my code will "understand" that blog "has an image" and will update the state with the new url.

So what I need is that in addition to checking if it has a url (as I already do), I need to check if that url returns an image before updating the state, but I don't know how to do that. It could even be with css (styled-component) if it were possible.

> I tried to create a function that takes the image url and makes an
> HTTP request, if it returns status 404 then I did not update the state
> of the url. But it did not work. Is there any direct treatment in the
> React components?

Comment: if the image is hosted on a url, you can do a simple request to server and check the response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097560/react-js-replace-img-src-onerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = () => setBlogBanner(image.src)
image.src = `$ {hlp.BACKEND_HOST} / images / blogBanners / $ {props.blog.image}`
```

which will preload the image, and if it loads successfully, you set the blog banner value to that src.

Comment: I tried this solution but whenever I define "new image ()" in a component, it returns the error.

Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: _ref is undefined