# What's the best way to replace image with default image on error in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, error-handling

I'm trying to create a replacement for the image if not found and below is what I have so far.
This is for a React project, so React answers only.

Any help will be great.

```
<img src={`${news.urlToImage.src ? news.urlToImage.src : "../assets/default_logo.png" }`} 
alt="images"/>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react.js Replace img src onerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097560/react-js-replace-img-src-onerror)

Answer (score 0):

You can have this approach here with uncontrolled component:

```html
<img src={this.state.img} ref={img => this.img = img} onError={
    () => this.img.src = 'img/default.img'
}>
```

Also, you can find the same question here - [react.js Replace img src onerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097560/react-js-replace-img-src-onerror)

Comment: If you find another question which has answers which answer this question, please flag this question as a duplicate of that other question, and don't answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hooks-style version of Lovekesh's answer:

```js
[imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState(
  news.urlToImage.src ? news.urlToImage.src : 
  "../assets/default_logo.png");
//...
<img src={imgSrc} onError={
  () => setImgSrc("../assets/default_logo.png"")
}/>
```