# image tag - how to put on an ICON (not string - NOT URL) in case of url failure?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I am using React.js as Frontend framework,

I have an icon from antd, and I want to put it in the 'alt' prop of an image tag,
so in case that the url I pass there will be null - it will go to put the icon there.

I tried using 'alt' but it only accepts string.
is it possible to put there an icon? (like one from antd?)

to emphasize - I want to add it as  -
`<Image alt={<StepBackwardOutlined />}`

as in in an actual icon and NOT AS A URL.

Comment: do you use additional library as js,Jquery,angular etc.? please add your code and what you tried so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react.js Replace img src onerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097560/react-js-replace-img-src-onerror)

Comment: no, that is how to add a url (string) as an alternative, i am looking for a way to add an icon - as I wrote in the question description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use on onError.
Inside onError you can create a function outside the main return for ex:-

```
const onErrorImage = ((e) => {
  e.target.src = <StepBackwardOutlined />
})
```

`<img onError={onErrorImage} />`

I never tried it with a component....and i never saw someone using it....so i am not sure that it will work or not.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work - throws the browser into an endless loop for api requests, I guess because 'src' expects a link and not an Icon

Comment: @TzachiElrom Well i tried another way of doing it......it is not a good way to handle this......but it is working.......Here is the link for it :- [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-neumann-zrcy0?file=/src/App.js) ......If you find it working you can use it in your project....I am mentioning again that it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: that's a funny workaround! thanks!
(though I do hope I won't have to use it)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) attribute.

From the docs:

```
<img src="imagefound.gif" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='logoIcon.jpg';" />
```

Here `logoIcon.jpg` is the icon path.

Comment: that's a url, not an icon..