# how to display default image when field image table is empty

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a **user** table, where the user is **currently logged on** and has not upload a photo **(that the image column in user table is empty)** images shown are Default.png. and if the user has uploaded the picture then the image is displayed.

what wrong in my code?

this is my table **'user'** on my database (i'm sorry i can't write database structure in here).

| id | gb_user | **= | 1 | me.jpg |**

this view (headers.php):

```
<?php $user_log = info_user_login();?>
                <?php if(!empty($user_log->gb_user) == NULL):?>
                  <img class="img-circle" src="../assets/img/default.png" width="70" style="margin:20px 0 0 10px;">
                 <?php else:?>
                  <img class="img-circle" src="../assets/img/<?php echo $user_log('gb_user');?>" width="70" style="margin:20px 0 0 10px;">
                  <?php endif;?>
```

this helper:

```
function info_user_login(){
$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->load->model('admin/setting_adm');
$get_data_login = $CI->setting_adm->get_data_log_user();
return $get_data_login;
```

}

and this model :

```
function get_data_log_user(){
    $id_login = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $this->db->where('id', $id_login);
    $this->db->from('user');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result();
}
```

**Where ID =  session_id_login**

Comment: What is the actual behavior of your code? In which cases it doesn't work: when user **has** photo, or when he **doesn't**, or **in both**? What is output in non-working cases?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(!empty($user_log->gb_user) == NULL):?>
```

This condition does not make sense, empty() will return a boolean.

try one of the following:

```
<?php if(empty($user_log->gb_user)):?>
<?php if($user_log->gb_user == NULL):?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

Use `ternary operator(:?)` to check whether you have image or not.

View:

```
<?php $user_log = info_user_login();
     $image = isset($user_log->gb_user)?"../assets/img/$user_log->gb_user":"../assets/img/default.png";//sets your image
    ?>
      <img class="img-circle" src="<?php echo $image;?>" width="70" style="margin:20px 0 0 10px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `empty()` function to check image are exist or not. That function will return `true` if there is no value in `gb_user` field.

```
<?php if( empty($user_log->gb_user) ): ?>
    <img class="img-circle" src="../assets/img/default.png" width="70" style="margin:20px 0 0 10px;" />
<?php else: ?>
    <img class="img-circle" src="../assets/img/<?php echo $user_log('gb_user');?>" width="70" style="margin:20px 0 0 10px;" />
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Js/HTML approach like here [HTML if image is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995080/html-if-image-is-not-found):

```
<img id="currentPhoto" src="SomeImage.jpg" onerror="this.src='Default.jpg'" width="100" height="120">
```

But instead of setting default image at beginning, create another hidden image

```
<img src="<?=$myImage?>" onerror="getElementById("default-img").src" />
```

Even if `$myImage` is null, php renders it as empty string, DOM look on this as error and event "onError" will triggered

Comment: I'm sorry you all the answers do not match

Comment: script still led to a default image. but already had my fill gb_user column in the database