# Detect if API url returns image or not

Tags: php, image, warnings, file-type

I have API `$url` which should return image depending on the request. 
It either returns an image or it doesn't return anything and then I get error `Failed to load resource: server responded with a statuf of 404`.

Just so you can imagine what I do, I am sending a request with a book ISBN number and API checks if it has a book cover for the ISBN in datatabase and if it does, I get book cover as image returned, but if it doesn't, I want to use my local book icon image instead.

I have tried to do something like this

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($url);
echo "Width: ".$width."<br/>";
echo "Height: ".$height."<br/>";

if($width==1 && $height==1){
   echo "<img src='../images/book_cover.png' alt='' class='cover'/>";
}else{
   echo "<img src=$url alt='' class='cover'/>";
}
```

But since `getimagesize()` does not return `FALSE`, I get php warning message.

Then I tried to use

```
if(!exif_imagetype($url)){
   echo "<img src='../images/book_cover.png' alt='' class='cover'/>";
}else{
   echo "<img src=$url alt='' class='cover'/>";
}
```

This works, but I get a warning `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed`.

Any ideas what will do the trick and make it all legit?

EDIT:

```
echo "<img src=$url onerror=\"this.onerror=null;this.src='../images/book_cover.png';\" alt='' class='cover'/>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle that directly in your html

[HTML if image is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995080/html-if-image-is-not-found)

Otherwise you still can check if url exists with a curl or file_get_contents but this would be slower

Comment: Got it to work, easy solution, thanks mate!