# Check image src is valid and replace if it is not

Tags: reactjs, image, react-hooks, error-handling

I'm loading a dynamic array of images, and i want to check the image src is valid, and if its not i want to replace it with a fallback image.

However, i just can't get it to work. It either doesn't display an image, or still returns an error of `cannot find module`

This is where I've got to:

```
import * as React from 'react';

// Import CSS
import './Card.scss';

// Import Material UI Components
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';

export default function Card ({
    card,
    handleCardClick,
}) {
    const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = React.useState(false);

    function checkImgSrc() {
        try {
            imgSrc = require(`../../images/cards/${card.card_img}`);
            setImgSrc(require(`../../images/cards/${card.card_img}`))
        } catch (ex) {
            setImgSrc(require('../../images/cards/blank.webp'));
        }
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        checkImgSrc();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} md={3} lg={2}>
            <div key={card.id} className="card" onClick={() => handleCardClick(card)}>
                <img
                    src={imgSrc}
                    style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}
                />
            </div>
        </Grid>
    )
};
```

Comment: Could try something with basic HTML image error handling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995080/html-if-image-is-not-found